# Zurb Foundation based CMS, preview effect of media queries

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I'm building a CMS based on Zurb Foundation, and one thing I'd really like to do is allow the user to switch between large/medium/small layouts via a button so that they can both preview how the page looks at this size, but also so they can set up columns etc. for different breakpoints.

Media queries are predicated on the window width, and I've been so far able to build something that my users find quite intuitive, and I feel that asking them to resize their browser window to change the mode seems a bit iffy.

An immediate way that I can think of would be to use an iframe for the main edit view, but the problem is that the page interactions I have are quite complex, drag & drop, drag to resize etc. - I have all of these working at present with both mouse and touch, and in order to drag & drop between the parent and an iframe I'd have to rewrite a significant amount of code. So I'd rather avoid this if at all possible.

I'm looking for suggestions/advice on how I could make this work - workarounds and hacks are fine.

This is how it looks at the moment, to give you an idea of the kind of interface I currently have - no live link that I can share atm, sorry:

[image: Foundation CMS]

Answer (score 0):

OK - this is the solution I've come up with so far - the whole page, not just the editor area goes in an iframe.

https://gist.github.com/nrkn/00e1fb7cc4c7b43329a3

https://cdn.rawgit.com/nrkn/00e1fb7cc4c7b43329a3/raw/69a85b12dda7cece2b7ed602503c45d16f898d15/iframe-rawgit.html